# How to enable single sign on and session sign on on apache karaf?

Tags: java, apache-karaf, karaf

I am having two applications (app1 and app2) deployed on apached karaf, both are working fine individually. I am trying to enable single sign on and session sharing between the two applications. But I am not able to find a tutorial to do this.

Can somebody please tell me how to achieve this in apache karaf ?

Answer (score 0):

If applications are in the same domaine you can share informations using cookie and you can manage authentication. But each application has its own session by nature.

Comment: Still - you can achieve SSO using other methods (basic authentication, SPNEGO, X509, federated (saml/oauth)), however - as mentioned in the previous answer - each application will have its own session. As well you can share a common datasource..

Comment: @GabrielVince I am using form authentication can you please tell me how to enable single sign on ?

Comment: Depends - what do you want? Basicis the simplest and it will certainly work (change FORM to BASIC in your web.xml), but not all users appreciate the look and feel.